# Trying to convert projects that werent built using Gradle

Tags: android-studio, github, compilation, android-gradle-plugin

I have tried to clone the following repository on GitHub using Android Studio, https://github.com/AlexKang/favr.git, but I have the error:

[image]

Before this I selected build project using Gradle and then accepted anything it wanted to install. I am having similar problems with, https://github.com/mb16/RemindEm.git, where I get that

[image]

Each time I selected "create project from existing sources" and then accepted everything it suggested.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there another piece of software, other than Android Studio, that it would be easier to import these projects into, in a more natural way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projects have eclipse `.classpath` files in the folder.  I'm guessing you should be able to import the project into eclipse.

As an alternative to using Eclipse you might want to try using a feature of `IntelliJ IDEA` (Android Studio's parent project).  `File > New > Project from Existing Sources...`  Then select the `.project` file for the import

[image]